# SparkJava before filter with WebSocket

Tags: java, websocket

I'm using [Spark Java](http://sparkjava.com/) to create a simple API.
Furthermore I've been using [spark-authentication](https://github.com/qmetric/spark-authentication) for basic authentication.

```
webSocket(ROUTE_WS, GarageWebsocket.class);

get(ROUTE_GARAGE_DOOR_STATE, GarageDoorController::getGarageDoorState);

put(ROUTE_GARAGE_DOOR_COMMAND_OPEN, GarageDoorController::openGarageDoor);
put(ROUTE_GARAGE_DOOR_COMMAND_CLOSE, GarageDoorController::closeGarageDoor);
put(ROUTE_GARAGE_DOOR_COMMAND_TOGGLE, GarageDoorController::toggleGarageDoor);
put(ROUTE_GARAGE_DOOR_COMMAND_STOP, GarageDoorController::stopGarageDoor);

before(new BasicAuthenticationFilter("/garage/*", new AuthenticationDetails(USERNAME, PASSWORD)));
```

The problem seems to be, that the before filter also applies to the websocket route.

Which is `/ws`.
The PUT routes starts with `/garage/...`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried calling before() after webSocket()?

Comment: @AlexC Yes and it doesn't work

Comment: Have you managed to integrate websockets with authentication?